# Nmap - in one command discover both UDP and TCP at the same time?

Tags: nmap

I need to discover the port 161 both UDP and TCP in big networks. And the results must have the output I chose below.

In order to discover TCP I use

```
nmap -T4 -sS -p T:161 -iL c:\input.txt -oN c:\output.txt --append-output –open
```

In order to discover UDP I use

```
nmap -T4 -sU -p 161 -iL c:\input.txt -oN c:\output.txt --append-output –open
```

I am looking for a command that will combine both of them. I need a list of both TCP and UPD results in one command, one result.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nmap allows you to combine scan types into a single scan, as long as you don't choose scan types that target the same protocols (e.g. `-sST`, which would request a TCP SYN and TCP Connect scan, an illegal combination). So your combined scan would be:

```
nmap -T4 -sSU -p 161 -iL c:\input.txt -oN c:\output.txt --append-output -–open
```

Unrelated note: If you have the disk space, I would highly recommend switching the `-oN` option for `-oA` or just adding `-oX` to get XML output. Lots of security tools can process this structured output and produce meaningful results. Plus, you don't have to worry when Nmap's screen output changes (which it does fairly regularly) and breaks your parsing scripts, since the XML is a much more stable and naturally extensible format.

Comment: Thank you. So the command `nmap -T4 -sSU -p 161` will scan the 161 to see if it's open or not, and will try both UDP and TCP?

Comment: @Pikk Yes. `-sSU` is the same as `-sS -sU`.